# jQuery Ajax silently failing for only a few users. How can I find the cause?

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging

I have an app which uses jQuery Ajax for interactivity. The page and app have been in place for over two months and >125k views, with no reports of problems. This week I received a few reports of people saying a list that Ajax should populate is blank.  I have tested in multiple browsers on Windows, Mac and iOS, and cannot reproduce the problem.

I have searched the server logs for errors from this page, but there are none.

For testing, I have copied the app into a page with no other content, and two users that have reported failure on the main page say the test page functions properly.

Based on my tests, it seems that something else on the page may be preventing my Ajax calls from running for those users. I can't ask the users to inspect with Firebug or Chrome dev tools. What method or tool can you recommend for me to determine the cause of this problem?

---

Edit: the page is at http://peregrinefund.org/peregrinecam-dyn , and the test page which two users have reported working on their system when the main page does not is at http://peregrinefund.org/temp/test-webcam-observe.php

---

Update May 28:  One of my colleagues had experienced the problem. Today I loaded the broken dynamic PHP version of the page on that computer, and it works just fine. I haven't changed anything since my posting here.

Comment: Are these requests making database queries? could you be possibly hitting a concurrent query limit? I would suspect the server/network before i suspect the client code if it's working more often than it's not.

Comment: @KevinB That should be recorded in the server log, no?

Comment: Is jQuery served from a CDN? I've had problems where some users couldn't reach the CDN.

Comment: First step would be to post some of your code here.

Comment: @tymeJV I don't know tbh. I haven't personally ran into that problem yet. I'm sure it would in *some* log, not sure which.

Comment: @Kevin B : The server files called by Ajax do make database queries. It is the same users reporting constant failure, regardless of when the page is loaded. The site had much heavier traffic - so more concurrent queries - a few days ago and this wasn't happening then.  Frison - jQuery is on our own server.  j08691, I will prepare some code for posting.

Comment: Is it always the same users that are reporting the issue? have you added any tracking to the javascript to report back to you when there is an issue so that you can get an idea of how many times it is failing and when it is failing?

Comment: The concurrent query limit was mroe of an example, there are several things that could go wrong depending on the server-side system you are using. For example, railo+tomcat is susceptible to "Connection Interrupted" when a request takes too long due to a locking bug. Also, even though only a select few users are reporting it, that doesn't mean a lot of other users aren't seeing it too.

Comment: Maybe too simplistic, but are you sure that these users haven't disabled Javascript?

Comment: @sage88, no, but I am fairly confident that they have not since a couple say the test page that also uses JS/jQuery/Ajax does work.

Comment: My original post has been edited to include links to the pages for inspection

Comment: Easy answer is that they have javascript turned off.

Comment: Nobody disables Javascript any more except paranoids, who can spend their own time to deal with the problems they inflict on themselves. Do you know, or can you find out, which browser the affected users are using? I've had similar trouble in the past where IE 7 failed to render some content because of a quirk in the way its Javascript parser behaved, which didn't play well with a change I'd made to one of my functions.